# Accessing OneToOneRel object in Django to perform search

Tags: python-3.x, django, one-to-one

I am working on a Django project, where we have created many relations between objects. In general - everything is working fine, expect - Frazesearch.

Below are my model classes:

Students.py

```
from django.db import models

from degreeCourse.models import DegreeCourse
from studentFinances.models import StudentFinances
from studentLoggingData.models import StudentLoggingData
from studentPersonalData.models import StudentPersonalData


# Create your models here.
# Part already after refactor
class Student(models.Model):
    personalStudentData = models.OneToOneField(
        StudentPersonalData,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=None
    )
    loggingStudentData = models.OneToOneField(
        StudentLoggingData,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=None
    )
    financesStudentData = models.ManyToManyField(
        StudentFinances
    )

    STUDENTS_UPLOAD_TO = "students/"
    image = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        upload_to=STUDENTS_UPLOAD_TO
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.personalStudentData.name} {self.personalStudentData.surname}"
```

StudentPersonalData.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class StudentPersonalData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        null=False,
        unique=False
    )
    surname = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        null=False,
        unique=False
    )
    personalIdNumber = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        null=False,
        unique=True
    )
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=False,
        unique=True
    )
    email = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        null=False,
        unique=True
    )
    streetAddress = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        null=True,
        unique=False
    )
    houseNumber = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        null=False,
        unique=False
    )
    flatNumber = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        null=True,
        unique=False
    )
    zipNumber = models.CharField(
        max_length=6,
        null=False,
        unique=False
    )
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        null=False,
        unique=False
    )
    isActive = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        null=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.surname}"
```

The problem is in views.py file for Student, where I'd like to search using data that is being held in studentPersonalData models.py.

```
 def form_valid(self, form):
        query_set_filter = Q(
            Q(personalStudentData_name__icontains=form.cleaned_data["frazeSearch"])
            |Q(personalStudentData_surname__icontains=form.cleaned_data["frazeSearch"])
        )
        return render(
            request=self.request,
            template_name=self.template_name,
            context={
                "form": form,
                "students": Student.personalStudentData.objects.filter(query_set_filter)
            }
        )
```

Using form_valid as present causes me an error like below:

```
AttributeError at /students/
'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'objects'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/students/
Django Version: 4.1.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

How am I supposed to do search based on inner object elements?

Comment: `Student.objects.filter(query_set_filter)`

Comment: I have also tried this one. Yet - it causes different error -

FieldError at /students/
Cannot resolve keyword 'personalStudentData_name' into field. Choices are: financesStudentData, grades, id, image, loggingStudentData, loggingStudentData_id, personalStudentData, personalStudentData_id, studentgroup, studentstudyingorder
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/students/
Django Version: 4.1.7
Exception Type: FieldError

Comment: `personalStudentData__name` with *double* underscores...

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem. I guess there is still a lot for me to learn -.-'